# Is it usual to pronounce, "English," as /ˈɪŋ·lɪʃ/

Tags: pronunciation

In many dictionaries, it says that we can pronounce "English" either as
**/ˈɪŋ·ɡlɪʃ/** or **/ˈɪŋ·lɪʃ/**. Do you think both of these pronunciations are used commonly? Do you think it is okay for a non-native English speaker to pronounce this word in either of these ways? Or should I stick with only one of them? I feel it might be more common to say, /ˈɪŋ·ɡlɪʃ/.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with IPA, but I think that's saying one might not pronounce the "g" as a consonant. I've never heard that usage. Can you cite the dictionaries you found it in?

Comment: @AndyBonner There are sites that convert IPA notation into speech like https://itinerarium.github.io/phoneme-synthesis/ (you have to delete the dashes though or it just pronounces the first syllable).

Comment: @AndyBonner https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/english https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/English https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/english

Comment: On the link to Cambridge, you will see the IPA **/ˈɪŋ·lɪʃ/** under American English. It's the same for Collins.

Comment: Many dictionaries also say we can say /ˈɪŋlənd/ instead of /ˈɪŋɡlənd/. Look at this please: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/England

Answer (score 2):

The /g/ will be naturally dropped in rapid pronunciation.  If you are speaking carefully and are conscious of the the pronunciation you do pronounce the /g/.  As a learner you should follow this: You should practice pronouncing the g. But you will find, as advanced learner, that it will be reduced or omitted without you being aware of it when you speak fast.

But if you still need to think about how to pronounce the word, then say the /g/

Comment: I think it would be strange to drop the /g/ in nearly any context, even when speaking rapidly.

Comment: I often notice omit the /g/ especially when I am talking more rapidly/fluidly, yeah. I heard an American Blues player say  **/ˈɪŋ·lɪʃ/** before. I think it was B.B. King.

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski Why do so many dictionaries say it can be pronounced /ˈɪŋ·lɪʃ/ then?

Comment: @FireandIce It seems you've found several dictionaries listing the pronunciation, and have heard it used yourself, so clearly it's "okay." Your original question, then, boils down to whether it's *advisable*, especially for a learner, and JamesK's advice is good. I'm an intermediate speaker of Spanish and French, and when I try to speed up my pace and take the kind of shortcuts native speakers do like eliding vowels, I find native speakers are less likely to understand me than if I simply speak slowly and enunciate all parts of a word.

Comment: Yeah, I'd agree.  I think sometimes we don't even notice the distinction between /g/ and  /ŋ·ɡ/--after all, that's presumably why the sound /ŋ/ is spelled "ng" whether or not a /g/ sound comes after it.